# boost::property_tree::ordered_end() missing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to iterate over a boost property tree.  The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/container.html) state that

> You can get an ordered view of all children by using ordered_begin()
>   and ordered_end().

However, when I write

```
for ( boost::property_tree::ptree::const_assoc_iterator it =
            myPropTree.ordered_begin();
    it != myPropTree.ordered_end();
    it++ )
```

The compiler complains

```
error: 'boost::property_tree::ptree' has no member named 'ordered_end'
```

```
boost v1.55
mingw
code::blocks
```

Comment: Looking at the [header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp), I do not see an `ordered_end()`, but there is `/** Returns the not-found iterator. Equivalent to end() in a real
          associative container.
         */
        assoc_iterator not_found();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The ptree documentation says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp204050352-bb):

> `assoc_iterator ordered_begin();`
>
> Returns an iterator to the first child, in key order.
>
> `const_assoc_iterator ordered_begin() const;`
>
> Returns an iterator to the first child, in key order.
>
> `assoc_iterator not_found();`
>
> Returns the not-found iterator. Equivalent to end() in a real associative container.
>
> `const_assoc_iterator not_found() const;`
>
> Returns the not-found iterator. Equivalent to end() in a real associative container.

So basically the`ordered_end` function is called `not_found`